# How do i convert this string into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, array.prototype.map

I need to convert this string into a an array into the format shown below.

itemString

```
[{"_id":"1e12345","a":"abc","b":def","c":ghi"},{"_id":"1e678910","a":"xzx","b":sed","c":ert"}]

var item=itemString.split("},{").map(function(i){
    return i
})
console.log(item)
```

what i need to get from  from console.log(item)

```
0:{_id:"1e12345",a:"abc",b:"def",c:"ghi"}
1:{_id:"1e678910",a:"xzx",b:"sed",c:"ert"}
```

what i get from console.log(item)

```
0:"[{"_id":"1e12345","a":"abc","b":"def","c":"ghi""
1:""_id":"1e678910","a":"xzx","b":"sed","c":"ert"}]"
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: perfect - thanks - exactly what i wanted- happy friday